# how can i add style attribute i post to page in ejs?

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

i want to add custom style. when i add it works but indicates a problem. My english is bad sorry :(

```
<div class="card card_applicant">
                <div class="card_title" style="background-color: <%= aday.Renk %>;" >
                    <h3 class="card-title"><%=(aday.Soyadi).toUpperCase() %></h3>
                </div>
```

its work but :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it disappear when you use template literals instead like so:

```
<div class="card_title" style="<%= `background-color: ${aday.Renk}` %>" >
   <h3 class="card-title"><%=(aday.Soyadi).toUpperCase() %></h3>
</div>
```